# Multiindex Value

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I've have the following Multiindex and I am trying to get the last time entry for a slice of the MultiIndex.

`df.loc['AUDCAD'][-1]`

would return `2019-04-30 00:00:00`

and

`df.loc['USDCHF'][-1]`

would return `2021-03-05 23:55:00`

`open     high      low    close`

````
AUDCAD 2018-12-31 00:00:00  0.95708  0.96276  0.95649  0.95979
       2019-01-31 00:00:00  0.96039  0.96309  0.92200  0.94895
       2019-02-28 00:00:00  0.94849  0.95800  0.93185  0.93655
       2019-03-31 00:00:00  0.93718  0.95632  0.93160  0.94745
       2019-04-30 00:00:00  0.94998  0.96147  0.94150  0.94750
USDCHF 2021-03-05 23:35:00  0.93109  0.93119  0.93108  0.93116
       2021-03-05 23:40:00  0.93116  0.93150  0.93116  0.93143
       2021-03-05 23:45:00  0.93143  0.93147  0.93127  0.93128
       2021-03-05 23:50:00  0.93129  0.93134  0.93117  0.93126
       2021-03-05 23:55:00  0.93126  0.93141  0.93114  0.93118```
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for :

```py
df.loc[block_name].index[-1]
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I spend several hours search for this to no available.

Comment: You're welcome. But then don't hesitate to validate and +1 the answer... ;)

Comment: I most certainly will, I'll be able to +1 once my reputation increase by another 4 points, hopefully this will be soon.

Comment: I don't think you need any privilege to accept the answer. And that's the normal way to do : it helps closing unnecessarily open questions...

Comment: I will bear that in mind - This is the response I get. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.